# Can I link files on DropBox onto a Trello card for members to see and so it updates when the file is changed?

Tags: trello, dropbox

I want to be able to link a spreadsheet to a card that it relates to while the file is on DropBox and have it update on Trello automatically so I don't have to re-upload it every time a change is made

Comment: are you asking if this is possible or is this a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attaching the file, you could use the [Dropbox link feature](http://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en). The resulting hyperlink would take the Trello member to a preview of the file with a download option. It is always the most recent version of the linked file.